# Not able to understand $q.all() behavior in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, javascript-debugger

I am just trying to export data into excel like this

```
purchaseRequestService.prototype.export = function (arrID, arrID_A) {
        var self = this;
        var q = $q.defer();
        var tasks = [];
        if (arrID.length > 0) {
            tasks.push(self.getDataForExportDashboard(arrID));
        }
        if (arrID_A.length > 0) {
            tasks.push(self.getDataForExportDashboard_A(arrID_A));
        }
        //$q.all(tasks).then(function (res) {
       // $q.all([self.getDataForExportDashboard(arrID),self.getDataForExportDashboard_A(arrID_A)]).then(function (res) {
          $q.all([ self.getDataForExportDashboard(arrID), self.getDataForExportDashboard_A(arrID_A)]).then(function (res) {
            var dt = [];

            if (res.length > 1) {
                dt.push(res[0][0].concat(res[1][0]));
                dt.push(res[0][1].concat(res[1][1]));
            } else {
                dt.push(res[0][0]);
                dt.push(res[0][1]);
            } 
            var q = $q.defer();
            ExcelService.exportDashboard(dt).then(function (result) {
                q.resolve(result);
            }, function (error, status) {
                q.reject({
                    error: result,
                    status: status
                });
            });
        });
        return q.promise;
    }
```

Now its kind of acting weird, sometimes the excel gets downloaded and sometimes not. When I open up debugger tools and stops the code at breakpoint, the download is successful. I am not able to understand what is happening.

Comment: It appears to be a matter of timing. When you debug it and pause the execution with a breakpoint, it would appear that you are giving time for some transfer to complete. You may wish to try using a promise to handle the arrival of the data **when it arrived** and not before.

Comment: Can you please help me editing the code for that?

Comment: That is not the purpose of SO (SW services). I think you are almost there however. You are returning a promise, so the only thing you need to do is to move to the `promise` the actual data manipulation.